# CSS media queries pixels not matching set width

Tags: css, responsive-design

Been trying to debug this for a couple of hours. I've been asked to fix a "responsive" website that is really buggy. I can't share the actual code b/c it's all on localhost on a secured network. Hoping you might see something have a light bulb go off from my description here.

Problem, we have @media (max-width:800px) and it stops affecting page elements around 600px wide.

Another example, i set `html{ max-width:1200px}` but to make the browser actually fit my 1200 pixel browser window I had to set it to 2250px.

My question is, does this ring any bells for anyone? I'm going through all the CSS and don't see any thing that immediately looks like the issue. These guys really broke responsive design.. bleh

Thanks..

EDIT

here's the meta tags that apply

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

... bunch of junk...

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` (again)

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with pixel-ratio. Usually this is implemented for Retina displays. Do you have anything of the kind in the code? Like ``-webkit-pixel-ratio`` in the ``media query``?

Comment: I haven't seen any thing like that in the CSS- searched all CSS files and did find some pixel-ratio: 2, but they're commented out. the media queries I am using to fix things are super simple max-width. Not checking orientation, or device, etc.

Comment: Maybe it's embedded somewhere in the HTML or in the other file? And also, what is shown in the Dev Tools regarding this 800px media query when the viewport's width is 600px?

Comment: At 626px wide i'm graduating from this media query (as Chrome sees it) media="screen" @media (max-width: 835px). I've attempted a search all (ctrl + f in chrome) and found 4 mentions of "pixel-ratio" haven't found anything that's declaring pixel ratio yet. I'll keep looking though, thanks.

Comment: found it. It's in js, which shouldn't be used for responsive layout in the first place. geez. thanks. Couldn't have found it without your pixel-ratio suggestion.. not where my brain was :)

Comment: You are welcome. Answer your own question then with some explanation as someone can occur with this further.

Answer (score 0):

With some help, I was able to resolve the issue.

Issue was related to pixel-ratio declaration but not in CSS, in minified Javascript...

Eliminating this unnecessary js made the page load as expected.

Core lesson: use javascript for functionality and CSS for design and layout.